# Getting "HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error)" while installing Codeigniter

Tags: server, lamp

I have no idea why this installation is giving me this problem but for some reason my lamp installation will not show the Codeigniter welcome page. At first I was getting:

```
403 forbidden
```

So I changed the permissions of the `/var/www/` folder but now I get:

```
HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error): An unexpected condition was encountered while
the server was attempting to fulfil the request.
```

I had everything working fine before I upgraded to 12.04 but since then, everything has fallen apart. I want the `/var/www/` folder set up in a way that I can install several folders with different frameworks and content management systems for my different projects.

I just need a little help getting this server issue worked out.

Answer (score 4):

Try to change your permission to 755

```
$ sudo chmod -R 755 /var/www/CodeIgniterInstallFolder/
```

If nothing happens, try to look on your server log.

```
$ sudo gedit /var/log/apache2/error.log
```

Comment: @kreshendo don't forget to mark an answer as accepted if it solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your server is probably not able to access the files required.
Just change the permissions on your application.
use these commands
`sudo chmod 777 -R /var/www/project`
`sudo chmod 777 -R /var/www/project/application`
OR
simply go to the path /var/www/project
right click > properties > permissions 
and set the permissions on folders as well as files.
I hope it will help.

Comment: As [dimis](http://askubuntu.com/users/83950/dimis) has asked: "How do I do that?" I recommend expanding this answer to explain this.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Ubuntu 16.04, 18.04 or 20.04 try this-

`sudo a2enmod rewrite` and restart your apache server
`systemctl restart apache2`

I hope it will solve your issue, it works for me.